# How to convert list into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to convert the list into dictionary where key is the integer stated in the list, and value is the frequency of number in the list.
for example,

list = [10,10,10,20,20,40,50]

then the dictionary would look like,

dict = { '10': 3, '20': 2, '40': 1, '50': 1}.

What would be the method for this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nlist = [10,10,10,20,20,40,50]
ndict = {}

for item in set(nlist):
    ndict[item] = nlist.count(item)
```

creates ndict:

```
{40: 1, 10: 3, 20: 2, 50: 1}
```

Comment: you mean 'l' by 'nlist', right? Thnx!

Comment: yes!  It's fixed now.